# How to use custom variable in magento custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-variable

I have created a custom module for send SMS at the time of order place, I have created a observer for this which works and send SMS to customer.
I have provide message field in system configration and want to send this message to customer but I don't know how to create and use custom variable {order_id} in sms configration setting.

System configration setting figure as below : 
[image]

As shown in above figure I want to use custom variable in message input field and want to send order_id from observer when message send.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strtr` It will translate parts of a string.

```
 $orderid = "51";
    $vars = array(
  '{$orderid}'       => $orderid,
  '{{order_id}}'        => $orderid,

);    

echo  strtr($data, $vars);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, Are you sure this is the correct way to replace {order_id} by $order_id, Is there not any another method for define and use variables?

Comment: defined method for emails you are not using the email template  so that is solution for you..